# UUID of OBD 2 dongle

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid, obd-ii

I'm try to develop Bluetooth connection with OBD 2 dongle and android phone.but I't doesn't work for me.I think Error occurs in wrong UUID.I'm using this [Dongle](http://www.ebay.com/itm/161049125919?ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWNX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649)I'm using this UUID
00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB is it correct? or what is the correct UUID  for this dongle

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400083/using-bluetoothchat-to-communicate-with-elm327

Answer (score 2):

The dongle you speak of is identified by a MAC address(Machine Address) called Bluetooth Address not UUID. UUIDs are for services such as SPP, OBEX etc. Try searching for the dongle's bluetooth address using a free version of Torque or some bluetooth application that will reveal its Bluetooth Address.Use that address to connect with it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a lot of OBD2 BTLE dongles changing their UUID on every startup. Better scan using the (fixed) service UUID rather than the device address.

Comment: Hi, what is the fixed service UUID? As this one indicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570070/how-to-use-ble-obdii-peripheral ?

Comment: @unruledboy This depends on the device. Although the service UUID is fixed as per the lifetime of the device, it is also variable, since there is no GATT standard for OBD2. If you want to work with all kinds of dongles, you will need to add a configuration phase to your program where you probe all available services whether they expose an OBD2 service or not. This service UUID you can then store and directly use on subsequent starts of your program.